# Create Scratch Org Definition file

Tags: salesforcedx, scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file, sourcecontrol, feature-management

To create a scratch org, a Scratch Org definition file should be created. Is there any way to identify the list of features and settings required?

Note: Our org has a lot of features as it is operating since more than 5 years. Now we are trying to move to source code deployment and Scratch Org based development.

Answer (score 7):

---

***Update (25 Oct 2020):*** With Winter'21 release, `enabling org shape` has been released to all environments. Although still in beta, it facilitates experimentation with org shape creation and easier scratch org creation as needed.

---

At the moment, I'm not aware of any tool available for free to help you draft the scratch org definition file. You may want to check whether paid tools like Gearset, Autorabit etc. has something to offer in this reference.

In lack of appropriate tool, you could start building the definition file from scratch (*which might most likely be a mundane & time consuming task*). For some help documentation, refer [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file.htm) & [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_scratch_orgs_def_file_config_values.htm).

- If you have some documentation and version control for the existing prod org, it might help you narrow down to the list of required features/ settings.
- Take precaution not to include every feature or setting into the scratch org definition (*as some of them might be critical, confidential or meant for prod only*) and run into errors (or performance degradation) with scratch orgs.

SFDX CLI command `force:org:shape:*` is meant to solve this problem (*which is still in beta*) and in order to test this out, you need to have `Org Shape` feature enabled in your org. I think the `Org Shape` feature is enabled as a pilot for very few orgs (*so, you might want to check if your production org was signed up for this*). Check out this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iDBb0RDqY2A), this latest [release notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_scratch_orgs_shape.htm) & this [section](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_shape_intro.htm) of SFDX dev guide. You may want to join this [community](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/_ui/core/chatter/groups/GroupProfilePage?g=0F93A0000009TPk) to participate in discussion and track some updates.

Comment: My Org Edition is *Unlimited*. So Org shape is not available. Is there any alternative way?

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, other than checking out paid tools or building a definition file from the scratch, I don't think there is any tool available out there at the moment. **You might want to check with SF support team whether they can enable shape for your org**.